# In Ipad scrolling is not smooth in codenameone

Tags: ipad, codenameone

In Ipad scrolling is not smooth in other devices(android/ios) and simulators(Including Ipad) also its scrolling smoothly.  don't know where i am doing wrong?

here is the code for finalContainer..

```
Container finalContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
finalContainer.setScrollableY(true);
finalContainer.setScrollVisible(false);
```

We are adding views to the container, In every view we have two images, one is loading from Theme and second one is loading using "setUIID()".

here is the code for item views..

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
Container itemContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
Image itemFirstImage = mTheme.getImage("item.png");
Label image = new Label(itemFirstImage);
itemContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseIn(image));

Container secondContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
secondContainer.setUIID("SecondImageContainer");
Container details = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
details.add(new Label("First Line"));
details.add(new Label("Second Line"));
details.add(new Label("Third Line"));
secondContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,details);
itemContainer.add(secondContainer);
finalContainer.add(itemContainer);
}
```

and final container added as `form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,finalContainer);` to Form.

I tried to resolve but failed, if any body have idea please guide me to achieve this..

Thanks.

Comment: How do you add `finalContainer` to the Form and what's the layout of the parent form?

Comment: form is with BorderLayout and i added final container to form as below.. form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,finalContainer);

Comment: This looks like it should be fine. Can you provide a video of what you are seeing?

Comment: sorry for late reply shai.. here is the video.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngfcjc92ao42faz/Scroll%20In%20Ipad.mp4?dl=0.. and sorry for the poor quality..

Comment: That does look horrible. What's in the theme.res file? Can you post a link to that?

Comment: here is the link for ItemContainer what we used theme.res..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1bu2yexj630prb/2018-03-09%20at%2011-07-06.mp4?dl=0

Comment: The actual res file not screenshots as there is too much information in that file to include in screenshots

Comment: here is the res file link shai.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yhdwa6th289nkr/theme.res?dl=0..

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see `item.png` in that theme. It looks like something is going on besides all of this. I suggest you create a separate hello world with a native theme and see the code there, then try to isolate the difference between your hello world and what you are seeing. Also use the performance monitor tool in the simulator to see what is drawn to the screen in every frame on that form

Comment: i am not using 'item.png' in the theme. i'm using border in the theme. for that item i used 'ItemContainer' in the theme. and i tried in sample hello world app also in that sample also it's happening same way ..

Comment: What device are we talking about here? Is this a first generation iPad?

Comment: no shai.. its a fourth generation iPad..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm seeing when I run your code, I replaced the `item.png` file with a duke image but the UI is still nothing alike what you have. It looks like you provided the wrong `theme.res` file for the project or that you are missing major pieces of code.

I suggest building a complete test case and isolating the problematic piece. Use the performance monitor tool in the simulator to see what is happening under the hood in terms of performance specifically look at the second tab.

[image]

Comment: here is the link for sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0glj75zthmnraw/ScrollSampleNew.rar?dl=0

Comment: Try disabling the round rect on the entries to see if this impacts your performance.

Comment: How did you set the round rect in the theme? The old (deprecated) round rect should be slow. The new one should have an initial performance cost but should be faster after that. I would use 9-piece borders if you want to make something like that at scale.

Comment: So that's the new one. It has an initial performance cost that as you can see is pretty significant and grows the larger the border is. Can you file an issue and reference this stack overflow post? I think this should work much faster for a solid color border and I think we can avoid some memory overhead too in this case.